# Modal Session requires Modal Window Error on Mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, interface-builder

I need to launch a modal window from a plugin in a video application. I created a Nib in Interface builder along with an NSWindowController class. But when I try to run the window like this

```
Registration* newWin = [[Registration alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Options"];

[NSApp runModalForWindow: [newWin window]];
```

It gives me an error in the Console : Modal Session requires Modal Window
I think it has something to do with Interface Builder (Pardon me, I am really new to IB).

Here is the link to the Nib file and the Classes. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what I did wrong in IB. Thanks.

[Link Removed]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You instantiated an instance of `Registration` in the nib file. That's not the way you prepare a nib file for use with an `NSWindowController`. That `Registration` object is a distinct object contained in the nib file, not the `Registration` object you allocated in the code you quoted above.

In the nib passed to `initWithWindowNibName`, the `File's Owner` **is** the `NSWindowController` instance you create in the code. So, in the inspector, set the class name of the `File's Owner` to be `Registration` and connect its `window` outlet to be your window object inside the nib file.

Comment: Ah! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks again! Worked like a charm.

Comment: I'm back to this answer *again* and *again* that was the problem on my end that was causing this error, thanks Yuji. Practice makes perfect, I guess, eventually I will learn to connect these.